# Why speech_to_text flutter is not listening the word. When try to speak it goes to speech Recognition error error_no_match aad error_network?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

What I find out the error "error_no_match" in speech recognition indicates that the speech-to-text system couldn't find a match for the audio input it received. and error_network indicates that there is no internet connection but error stays still where if one time error accrued then the speech to text does not works anymore.

I am expecting to know whether I can fix the if error comes speech_to_text does not work at all.